# Встраивание компонентов в Ext.XTemplate

Tags: javascript, extjs

Пытаюсь понять как встроить exjs компоненты в xtemplate.

Данные:

```
    "data": [
       {"id":1,"started_at":"22.04.2016","name":"same title","score":"value","ratio1":-202,"ratio2":-303,"ratio3":1147,"selection":1,"statistic":"1, 22, 12"},
       {"id":1, "started_at":"22.04.2016", "name":"same title","score":"value", "ratio1":-202, "ratio2":-303, "ratio3":1147, "selection":1, "statistic":"1, 22, 12"}
    ]
```

Код:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Component', {
                id: this.myClassName + data.id,
                renderTo: Ext.get(Ext.query(".results-container." + this.myClassName + " > table")),
                tag: 'table',
                cls: 'results-container-inner',
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<tpl for="data">',
                           '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="results-row" data-id="{id}">',
                              '<tr>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{id}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{started_at}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{name}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top"><a href="#" class="stat-open" data-id="{id}">{value}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{ratio1}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{ratio2}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top">{ratio3}</td>',
                                 '<td valign="top" class="btn" data-num="{id}"></td>',
                                 '<td valign="top" class="cbox" data-num="{id}"></td>',
                              '</tr>',
                           '</table>{statistic}',
                        '</tpl>'),
                listeners: {
                    afterrender: function (el) {
                        var renderEl = el.getEl().down('td.btn');
                        new Ext.Button({
                            text: 'test',
                            renderTo: renderEl
                        });
                    }
                }
            });

row.update(data);
```

Есть идея делать так:

```
var parent = this;
            Ext.get(Ext.query(".results-container." + this.myClassName + " > table .btn")).each(function () {
                new Ext.Button({
                    text: 'test',
                    tooltip: 'test',
                    renderTo: this,
                    handler: parent.btnHandler,
                    scope: parent
                });
            });
```

Но мне это кажется костылем, есть ли решение что бы добавить в afterrender? С помощью alert я выяснил что контент появляется после этого события.